# Set a project in Apache flex?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, fdt

can any one tell me about step by step configuration of Apache flex . I have a project code but I can't understand how to set it at local and run this programme .
I have read the documentation of Apache flex but I can't understand the settings . I have downloaded the software development kit for Apache but I can't understand how to run this ?

Comment: I think your question is confusing, at least to me.  What are you trying to configure?  For what purposes?  Are you using an IDE, such as Flash Builder and trying to create a flex project?  Or are you trying to build the Flex SDK from the Apache Flex source?  What documentation did you read?  Why didn't it help?  What exactly did you download from Apache?

Comment: ok i have a web which is developed in apache flex or some thing i have to fix some errors so i want to set it on local . i have downloaded Flash builder & eclipse which i can understand from some where so now what i have to do next?

Comment: I think you need to download the Apache Flex Installer ( http://flex.apache.org/installer.html )and run it.  It should create the Apache Flex SDK for you. Once you have that; you can add the Apache Flex SDK to Flash Builder. (Window--> Preferences --> Apache Flex --> Installed Flex SDKs --> Add ).  Then you can create projects with the Apache Flex SDK and load in your source code to make changes / recompile / etc..

Comment: I think your 'solution' is as confusing as your question. It is possible you are confusing things such as "installing/setting up Java" or "installing an IDE" with installing/using the Apache Flex SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the real solution 1st download the Apache Flex sdk. then download flex development tool (FDT). and finally download and install JDK.

then it needs some settings for JDK...
For Windows 7: 1. Right click on My Computer. 2. Go to Properties. 3. Click on Advanced system settings. 4. Click on the Advanced tab. 5. Click the Environment Variables button. 6. Under system variables, find the 'Path' variable, select it and click the Edit button.
 1. Add a semicolon to the end of the path value and then paste in the path to your java bin folder. Example: %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\Syste‌​m32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin <--Appended path. 8. Click Ok.
 9. Back in the Advanced tab, under System variables, click the New button. 10. Under Variable name, enter JAVA_HOME. 11. Under Variable value, enter the path to your jre. Example jre path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre

Check this link for further details

http://coranguweb.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/
http://coranguweb.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/